# How to remove the garbage value read from the file?

Tags: c, file, garbage

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 50
struct Visitor
{
        char name[20];
        int y;
        char pass[20];
        int age;
        int oku;
        float price;
};

main()
{
        struct Visitor Data[N];

        FILE *fdata;
        int i = 1;

        fdata = fopen("data.txt", "r"); // read mode

        if (fdata == NULL)
        {
                perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {

                while (EOF != fscanf(fdata, "%s\t,%d\t,%s\t,%d\t,%d\t,%.2f\n", Data[i].name, &Data[i].y, Data[i].pass, &Data[i].age, &Data[i].oku, &Data[i].price))
                {

                        printf("%s\t,%d\t,%s\t,%d\t,%d\t,%.2f\n", Data[i].name, Data[i].y, Data[i].pass, Data[i].age, Data[i].oku, Data[i].price);
                        i++;
                }
        }
        fclose(fdata);
        return 0;
}
```

Turns out, all the contents of my file were shown on the left part of the screen, followed by some garbage values at each row. Is there any problem with my coding above? How should I eliminate the garbage values? Please help..

Attached is my sample output. (The one on the left part is my file content)[image: output]

[data.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpqY5.jpg)

Comment: Why are you comparing `fscanf()`s returned value with `EOF` only?

Comment: Show `data.txt`

Comment: Read `sscanf` documentation, about its return value. It's not enough to test it against `EOF`. You also have to check if `sscanf` successfully parsed all the items you asked it to. As first step, read the return value to a variable to keep things simpler.

Comment: Is input files separated by tab and  commas?

Comment: Please provide some snippet from your input file. Are the values on a new line each? What does your favourite debugger unveil if you step into your loop?

Comment: Remove the `.2` from `%.2f` in the `fscanf` statement - it's nonsense. While you are at it remove all the `\t`s to. The format specifiers `%s` and `%d` and `%f` all ignore whitespace, so you are cluttering the code unnecessarily.

Comment: hi xing may I know why are you adding 19 for the %s? it does works! @xing thank you so much!

Comment: well now I understood, that's a big help! thank you so much! @xing

Comment: @xing that makes sense.. omg i finally solved my problem after trying it for the whole day, thank you so much and the others too thank you so much

Comment: @KeanPinNg You can post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @chux better recommend to delete the question instead?

Comment: @machine_1 Perhaps.  In any case, OP should complete this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
# define N 50
 struct Visitor{
  char name[20];
  int y;
  char pass[20];
  int age;
  int oku;
  float price;
 };

 main(){
  struct Visitor Data[N];

   FILE *fdata;
 int i=1;


   fdata = fopen("data.txt","r"); // read mode

   if( fdata == NULL )
   {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   else{

  while (EOF!=fscanf(fdata,"%19s%d%19s%d%d%f", &Data[i].name, &Data[i].y, &Data[i].pass, &Data[i].age, &Data[i].oku, &Data[i].price )){

  printf("%s\t,%d\t,%s\t,%d\t,%d\t,RM%.2f\n", Data[i].name, Data[i].y, Data[i].pass, Data[i].age, Data[i].oku, Data[i].price);
i++;
  }



}

   fclose(fdata);
   return 0;
}
```